# SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe2' in file {the location of the thing} line 138, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/

Tags: python, url-rewriting, discord, discord.py

I have a list named quotes, with a lot of JoJo quotes, and I get that error there when I try to execute. The same error happens when I change all the  ' to ".

```py
quotes = ['Perhaps… Perhaps the time he foretold has come. If this is my destiny, I accept it. - Zeppeli', 'You truly are the lowest scum in history. You can’t pay back what you owe with money. - Jotaro Kujo', 'Impossible? We did a lot of impossible things on this journey. I’m tired of hearing that things are impossible or useless. Those words mean nothing to us. - Jotaro Kujo', 'Shoot me if you want to! But you better be prepared to face the consequences. The moment you try to pull that trigger, I’ll snap your fingers in half like matchsticks! - Joseph Joestar', 'would you be able to pull of a command that randomly generates a jojo quote when you use it - kirbs', 'What? The loser is evil? Well, in that case… you’re the evil one after all! The one who will be the judge is my Stand! - Jotaro Kujo', 'You’re god damn right! Everything worked out according to the plan… From the very beginning! (I just got lucky, but thinking I outsmarted him will drive Kars nuts). - Joseph Joestar', 'You’ve got to say something more like this before you get revenge. My name is Jean-Pierre Polnareff. For my sister’s honor, and so that my friend Avdol can rest in peace... Im going to hurl you into the depths of despair! - Jean-Pierre Polnareff', 'The ultimate being embodies the powers of each and every living thing, all lives gather as one. And… How beautiful it shines! Truly the most wonderful thing I have ever beheld… I have finally, finally tamed the sun! - Kars', 'I shall give you a chance. Go down two steps and I’ll let you join my side again. But if you rather die, then climb those stairs. - Dio Brando' 'KONO DIO DA! - Dio  Brando', 'I, Giorno Giovanna, have a dream. - Polpo', 'What did you say? Depending on your answer, I may have to kick your ass! - Joseph Joestar']
```

Comment: Is this python 3.x? Is your editor saving in utf-8? You should be able to trim this to a few line program demonstrating the problem. Likely you are using a windows code page encoding and the offending character is `"…"`. It will work for us because your paste into SO was utf-8. You could paste that one character into your editor and save it. Then `print(open('mytestfile', 'rb').read())`. If that is a single character, you are using a code page. If its `b'\xe2\x80\xa6'` then you have utf-8.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.8 or 3.7, I forgot which one, I'm using sublime text. I also deleted all the characters that are "..." since yeah, they were one character, and changed them to 2 dots, but nothing changes. still the same error

Answer (score 0):

It's not a code problem. User better IDE to edit your Python code instead

If you're using Notepad++, click Encoding at the top and choose Encode in UTF-8.

If not then check your locale encoding by executing:

```
import locale
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())
```

And if UTF-8 is not shown then set your env variable in Sublime Text as:

```
"env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8", "LANG": "en_US.UTF-8"},
```

through `Tools->Build System->New Build System` for python.

Comment: I agree that its very likely OP's editor is not saving as utf-8. But adding the encoding statement won't help.

Comment: I'm using Sublime text. I have the exact same statement except with different words in my code and no error. This one in particular has an error.

Comment: uh yeah its too long

Comment: Please check this code `import locale
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())` and if it will not show UTF-8 then set env variable of your locale.

Comment: Please check [online](https://onlinegdb.com/B1HvP1Xev)